# DocuSignApi - how to set the email message sent

Tags: email, docusignapi, document-body

Looking at the DocuSignAPI, I cannot see where one can set the body text of the email generated that accompanies the email.  How can I assure my prospect, being asked to sign a document, that it is from me - and reiterate the instructions and who to call if there's a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the body of the email by using the **emailBlurb** property in the **CreateEnvelope** REST API Request.

Comment: Thank you.  It worked.  For others hunting around, it's at the same level as emailSubject.

Comment: Glad I could help!